# Catch mouse event on tree widget item in QTreeWidget

Tags: mouseevent, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem, qt5.6

In tree widget I have following signal connected:

```
  connect(mTreeWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)),
          SLOT(onItemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)));
```

where `onItemClicked()` slot is following:

```
void WidgetBox::onItemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int )
{
  int index = getPageIndex(item);
  setCurrentIndex(index);
}

int WidgetBox::getPageIndex(QTreeWidgetItem *item)
{
  if (!item) return -1;

  QTreeWidgetItem *parent = item->parent();
  if(parent)  // Parent is top level item
  {
    return mTreeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(parent);
  }
  else        // Current item is top level
  {
    return item->treeWidget()->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
  }
}

void WidgetBox::setCurrentIndex(int index)
{
  if (index != currentIndex() && checkIndex(index))
  {
    mTreeWidget->setCurrentItem(mTreeWidget->topLevelItem(index));
    emit currentIndexChanged(index);
  }
}
```

However I can't catch `itemClicked()` signal and `onItemClicked()` never executed because top level items has push button widget (set with `setItemWidget()` method) which intercepts mouse event and child items contain container widgets which may have any widget combinations in them.

Is there a good method here to invoke this `itemClicked()` signal for both top level and child items of tree widget?

- installEventFilter() for all widgets found in an item by something like following:
  `QList<QWidget *> widgets = parentWidget.findChildren<QWidget *>();`?
- Or establish [mouse event propagation](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/) somehow?
- QCoreApplication::postEvent()?

How to organize such process better so all widgets process mouse event as they need to and TreeWidget issue `SIGNAL(itemClicked())` as well?

> Full sources to reproduce: https://github.com/akontsevich/WidgetBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solution is simple and following - just re-send `void itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column);` signal in `PageEventFilter`:

```
PageEventFilter::PageEventFilter(QObject *parent, QTreeWidgetItem *item)
  : QObject(parent)
  , mItem(item)
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)),
          mItem->treeWidget(), SIGNAL(itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*,int)));
}

bool PageEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
  {
    // Resend signal to QTreeWidget
    emit itemClicked(mItem, 0);
    return false; // Send event to the object (do not filter it)
  }
  else
  {
    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
}
```

> P.S. Will leave previous answer as well if somebody needs code or idea.

Answer (score 0):

Created event filter like this:

```
class PageEventFilter : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  PageEventFilter(QObject *parent, QTreeWidgetItem *item);

protected:
  bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

private:
  QTreeWidgetItem *mItem;
};

bool PageEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
  {
    // Emitate mouse event for parent QTreeWidget
    QMouseEvent *oldEvent = (QMouseEvent *)event;
    QRect itemRect = mItem->treeWidget()->visualItemRect(mItem);
    QPointF mousePos(itemRect.x() + 1, itemRect.y() + 1);
    QMouseEvent *newEvent = new QMouseEvent(oldEvent->type(),
                                            mousePos,
                                            oldEvent->button(),
                                            oldEvent->buttons(),
                                            oldEvent->modifiers());
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(mItem->treeWidget(), newEvent);
    return false; // Sent event to the object (do not filter it)
  }
  else
  {
    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
}
```

Install it to a button in tree widget item. It creates and sends (imitates) mouse event to tree widget, however tree widget still does not send itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int) signal. What is the problem could be? Wrong mouse pos? Tried to send event to **viewport()** - no luck as well. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Workaround could be to create own `itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)` signal and send it directly from event filter class to QTreeWidget->itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem*, int) signal. But why current implementation does not work? :)